# Playframework : forward to new page is very very slow

Tags: playframework-1.x

I have a two actions:

```
public static void save(String[] data) {
    // Do something with "data", but actually doesn't take too much time.
    detail();
}

public static void detail() {
    render();
}
```

When I post data to `save` action and the `data` is a little large(e.g. 600KB), the `detail`'s `render()` will be very very slow.

I know it's stucked in `detail` function because I can see browser URL has immediately turned to `/detail`.

This is wired, I can understand if it stucked in `save`, but can't understand why it stuck in `detail`. There actually no where cost a lot of time.

Any explain or solution for this ? Thanks !

NOTE: I'm using Play 1.x

Comment: what is being rendered in detail?

Comment: Nothing special, just an empty page.

Comment: can you possibly share the details page template? Also, I'm curious - how long does it take after your save operation and the detail rendering - have you tried time statements and can you share them?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not specifically solving your problem, the best approach to solving this problem is to change the following setting in your `application.conf`.

```
# application.log=DEBUG
```

remove the # symbol to uncomment, and you will see a lot of debug information from Play of what it is doing, and the time taken to perform certain actions.